# Change MyEntityFrameworkModel.edmx.cs File

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I was wondering if can change the edmx.cs file (change inheritance and base constructors of object context derived class).
when I try this , all changes will defect as i build the project.
Note I mean changing the object context derived class not entity classes.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can afford it (meaning if your project is not too complex already), I could suggest that you switch to code-first style (EF 4.1).  That allows you to build all the inheritance you want in your objects.  And since you create your own context by inheriting DbContext, you also have total flexibility there.

You can use your EDMX (with the T4 template packed in EF 4.1) or your existing database to create the classes (so at least what you have done until today still stands).

http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/quick-look-at-reverse-engineer-db-into-code-first-classes/

http://devlinliles.com/post/Reverse-Engineer-Code-Firste28093Jump-start-for-existing-Databases.aspx

The partial class solution would maybe do it too (depending on what you wish to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

To change in entity frame work class its better to create  Shared classes with same name  and add your own methods and properties

Comment: :what if i want to change object context derived class ? thanks